# Rails 5 and RethinkDB Error storing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rethinkdb

Simple Blog app in Rails / Rethinkdb / nobrainer gem

model

```
class Post
include NoBrainer::Document
include NoBrainer::Document::Timestamps
field :title, :type => String
field :body, :type => Text
```

controller

```
def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

works fine with Rails 4 same in Rails 5 error:

Some idea ??

```
To assign attributes, please pass a hash instead of `ActionController::Parameters'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with NoBrainer. It's already been fixed in the current git HEAD release, and will be included in the next update release.

**Do not** simply bypass Strong Parameters by converting `post_params` to a hash as previously suggested; this will allow any user to submit any form fields they wish, and your application will blindly accept it. This is a huge security issue, as any attacker can now pass arbitrary column data (like, say, "is_admin = 1") and your app will cheerfully accept them with no qualms.

If you ever convert parameters to a hash, you are making the wrong decision. You should never be passing raw params into a model from a controller. Strong Parameters is there to protect you. If the `permit` and `require` white lists aren't working, Rails or your ORM is broken. Stop, figure out which one is broken, and report it to the appropriate project.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message `To assign attributes, please pass a hash instead of 'ActionController::Parameters'` I assume somewhere in your app have a code:

```
Post.create(post_params)
```

Convert to a hash with the [`to_h`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h) method:

```
Post.create(post_params.to_h)
```

Comment: Nooo! While this "solves" the problem, it renders Strong Parameters completely useless and introduces a huge security flaw.

Comment: @colinm Is there a raw params here? `post_params` it is _permitted params_, and only a two keys allowed `title` and `body` and only two key passed to the create method. Read carefully.